# Created object is not using updated global variable values

Tags: python

I have the following code in `main.py`:

```
import json
from data import message    # data.py
from definitions import *   # definitions.py

waypoints=[]
stations=[]
genes = []

jsonObj = json.loads(message) # from data.py

for item in jsonObj:
  location = Location(id=item["id"], name=item["name"], lat=item["lat"], lon=item["lon"])
  if ("is-start" in item) or ("is-end" in item):
    location.isWaypoint = True
    if "is-start" in item:
      start = location
    else:
      end = location
  else:
    genes.append(location)
    if "is-waypoint" in item:
      location.isWaypoint = True
      waypoints.append(location)
    else:
      stations.append(location)
```

Then, I have the following code in `definitions.py`:

```
from haversine import haversine

start = None
end = None
distMatrix = {}

def distBtwn(loc1, loc2):
  dist = 0
  pair = frozenset((loc1.id, loc2.id))
  if pair in distMatrix:
    dist = distMatrix[pair]
  else:
    coords1 = (loc1.lat, loc2.lon)
    coords2 = (loc2.lat, loc2.lon)
    dist = haversine(coords1, coords2)
    distMatrix[pair] = dist
  return dist

class Location:
  def __init__(self, id, name, lat, lon):
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
    self.lat = lat
    self.lon = lon
    self.isWaypoint = False

  def __repr__(self):
    rep = ""
    if self.isWaypoint:
      rep += "Waypoint "
    else:
      rep += "Station "
    rep += "%d: %s (%f, %f)" % (self.id, self.name, self.lat, self.lon)
    return rep

class Fitness:
  def __init__(self, route):
    self.route = route
    self.distance = 0.0
    self.fitness = 0.0

  def routeDistance(self):
    if self.distance = 0.0:
      global start
      global end
      print(start)
      print(self.route[0])
      print(self.route[-1])
      print(end)
      pathDistance = distBtwn(start, self.route[0]) + distBtwn(self.route[-1], end)
      for i in range(len(self.route) - 1):
        pathDistance += distBtwn(self.route[i], self.route[i + 1])
      self.distance = pathDistance
  return self.distance
```

I run `main.py`, then entered the following in the shell, which throws an error:

```
>>> start
Waypoint 0: startPoint (3.333333, 3.333333)
>>> end
Waypoint 2: endPoint (4.444444, 4.444444)
>>> route = [waypoints[0], stations[15], waypoints[1]]
>>> fitA = Fitness(route)
>>> fitA.routeDistance()
None
Waypoint 1: waypointA (1.111111, 1.111111)
Waypoint 3: waypointC (2.222222, 2.222222)
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#78>", line 1, in <module>
    fitA.routeDistance()
  File "definitions.py", line 54, in routeDistance
    pathDistance = distBtwn(start, self.route[0]) + distBtwn(self.route[-1], end)
  File "definitions.py", line 10, in distBtwn
    pair = frozenset((loc1.id, loc2.id))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
>>> start
Waypoint 0: startPoint (3.333333, 3.333333)
>>> end
Waypoint 2: endPoint (4.444444, 4.444444)
```

Based on the above, `routeDistance()` is using the original `None` values of `start` and `end` from initialisation, even though they've been declared as global variables. Yet when called from the shell, those two variables have already been updated correctly with `Location` objects assigned. What is going wrong here?

Comment: `from definitions import *` is a *one-time copying* of the global names from one module into the current one - you won't see the result of any subsequent assignment to those names.  You need to do `import definitions` instead, and refer to `definitions.start`, etc., which is always getting the current value from the imported module.

Comment: @jasonharper but the function `routeDistance()` is from the same module as `start` and `end`. Why does it not get the updated values? `start` and `end` aren't used in `main.py`.

Comment: @jasonharper I tried changing to `import definitions` like you said, but it still throws the same error. Changing the code to `definitions.start` in `routeDistance()` throws `NameError: name 'definitions' is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global variables are scoped to a module.

For example, in `foo.py`:

```
def set_variable(to):
    global variable
    variable = to
variable = None
```

And `bar.py`:

```
import foo

def get_variable():
    global variable  # Unnecessary, but to avoid confusion
    return variable

variable = 1
print(foo.variable)  # None
foo.set_variable(2)  # Sets `foo`'s global variable to `2`
print(get_variable())  # 1; `bar`'s global variable is still 1
print(foo.variable)  # 2; `foo`'s global variable is now `2`
```

You need to set `definitions.start` and `definitions.stop`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow. In my case, the function `routeDistance()` which uses `start` and `end` are in the same file/module, not separate.

Comment: @thegreatjedi When you modify them in `main.py`, it doesn't change it in `definitions.py`

Comment: Oh, I got it now. I was only looking within `definitions.py` and forgot about the calls from `main.py`. Thanks!